# Make coffeescript to compile files but not to interpret it

Tags: coffeescript

How can i make coffee command to compile javascript files but not to interpret them.

This is the command i am currently using in terminal.

```
coffee --watch js/
```

It is working fine for me. It is compiling all `.coffee` files in js directory to respective `.js` files. But in terminal it is also giving RefrenceError: Backbone not defined. So instead to interpret i want coffeescript to compile only my files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`coffee --compile --watch` works for me.

Comment: Yeah, it's working for me too. But it's also giving RefrenceError: Backbone not defined.

Comment: Are you sure that's coming from the coffeescript compilation process? Do you have a node app running as a background job in the same terminal or something?

Comment: No this is for sure that errors are from coffeescript i am using the latest version 1.6.2

Comment: Well, something is totally whack. You can use undefined names all you want and coffeescript will happily compile it. Something is whack on your system but I can't speculate as to what. The problem isn't coffeescript itself. You've got something bizarre like a messed up PATH or a shell alias or something along those lines I suspect.

Comment: Yes, that might help. Thanks for you efforts.